# my SMTP sender throws an error 421

Tags: java, smtp

My code works as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SMTPClientDemo {
  protected int port = 25;
  protected String hostname = "localhost";
  protected String from = "";
  protected String to = "";
  protected String subject = "";
  protected String body = "";
  protected Socket socket;
  protected BufferedReader br;
  protected PrintWriter pw;

  public SMTPClientDemo() throws Exception
  {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try
    {
        getInput();
        sendEmail();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Error sending message - " + e);
    }
 }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // Start the SMTP client, so it can send messages
    SMTPClientDemo client = new SMTPClientDemo();
 }
// Check the SMTP response code for an error message
protected int readResponseCode() throws Exception
{
    String line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("< "+line);
    line = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(" "));
    return Integer.parseInt(line);
}

// Write a protocol message both to the network socket and to the screen
protected void writeMsg(String msg) throws Exception
{
    pw.println(msg);
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println("> "+msg);
}

// Close all readers, streams and sockets
protected void closeConnection() throws Exception
{
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    br.close();
    socket.close();
}

// Send the QUIT protocol message, and terminate connection
protected void sendQuit() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Sending QUIT");
    writeMsg("QUIT");
    readResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Closing Connection");
    closeConnection();
}

// Send an email message via SMTP, adhering to the protocol known as RFC 2821
protected void sendEmail() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Sending message now: Debug below");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Opening Socket");
    socket = new Socket(this.hostname,this.port);
    System.out.println("Creating Reader & Writer");
    br = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    pw = new PrintWriter(new
    OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("Reading first line");
    int code = readResponseCode();
    if(code != 220) {
        socket.close();
        throw new Exception("Invalid SMTP Server");
    }  
    System.out.println("Sending helo command");
    writeMsg("HELO "+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    code = readResponseCode();
    if(code != 250)
    {
        sendQuit();
        throw new Exception("Invalid SMTP Server");
    }
    System.out.println("Sending mail from command");
    writeMsg("MAIL FROM:<"+this.from+">");
    code = readResponseCode();
    if(code != 250)
    {
        sendQuit();
        throw new Exception("Invalid from address");
    }
    System.out.println("Sending rcpt to command");
    writeMsg("RCPT TO:<"+this.to+">");
    code = readResponseCode();
    if(code != 250)
    {
        sendQuit();
        throw new Exception("Invalid to address");
    }
    System.out.println("Sending data command");
    writeMsg("DATA");   
    code = readResponseCode();
    if(code != 354)
    {
        sendQuit();
        throw new Exception("Data entry not accepted");
    }
    System.out.println("Sending message");
    writeMsg("Subject: "+this.subject);
    writeMsg("To: "+this.to);
    writeMsg("From: "+this.from);
    writeMsg("");
    writeMsg(body);
    code = readResponseCode();
    sendQuit();
    if(code != 250)
    throw new Exception("Message may not have been sent correctly");
    else
    System.out.println("Message sent");
}

// Obtain input from the user
protected void getInput() throws Exception
{
    // Read input from user console
    String data=null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Request hostname for SMTP server
    System.out.print("Please enter SMTP server hostname: ");
    data = br.readLine();
    if (data == null || data.equals("")) hostname="localhost";
    else
    hostname=data;
    // Request the sender's email address
    System.out.print("Please enter FROM email address: ");
    data = br.readLine();
    from = data;
    // Request the recipient's email address
    System.out.print("Please enter TO email address :");
    data = br.readLine();
    if(!(data == null || data.equals("")))
    to=data;
    System.out.print("Please enter subject: ");
    data = br.readLine();
    subject=data;
        System.out.println("Please enter plain-text message ('.' character on a blank line signals end of message):");
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    // Read until user enters a . on a blank line
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            // Check for a '.', and only a '.', on a line
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("."))
            {
                break;
            }
            buffer.append(line);
            buffer.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        buffer.append(".\n");
        body = buffer.toString();
    }

}
```

Compiling went OK, when I tried to run it, it results in:

```
 Please enter SMTP server hostname: mail.telkomsel.com
 Please enter FROM email address: andikacj@aim.com
 Please enter TO email address :kamikaze273@gmail.com
 Please enter subject: coba
 Please enter plain-text message ('.' character on a blank line signals end of message):
 coba14
 .
 Sending message now: Debug below
 -------------------------------------
 Opening Socket
 Creating Reader & Writer
 Reading first line
 < 220 ESMTP mail.telkomsel.com
 Sending helo command
 > HELO Cruzer-PC
 < 250 mailpapp1.telkomsel.co.id
 Sending mail from command
 > MAIL FROM:<andikacj@aim.com>
 < 250 2.1.0 Ok
 Sending rcpt to command
 > RCPT TO:<kamikaze273@gmail.com>
 < 250 2.1.5 Ok
 Sending data command
 > DATA
 < 354 end data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 Sending message
 > Subject: coba
 > To: kamikaze273@gmail.com
 > From: andikacj@aim.com
 > 
 > coba14
 .

 < 421 syntax error (wait for server response)
 Sending QUIT
 > QUIT
 < null
 Error sending message - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The one I can assure is the 421 means that the problem may be on the server, but which server??

Any helps would appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is sent by `mail.telkomsel.com`, the server you are communicating with.

To prevent spam, most servers won't accept to send emails with a from address outside of their domain and without proper authentication. The error code 421 actually means *Service not available*. That's a way to say *Go away!* to spammers.